# Obtener información de archivo Excel en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

El inconveniente es que el archivo Excel tiene encabezados por lo tanto tengo que importar desde una fila específica hacia abajo hasta que encuentre una fila en blanco que indicaría el fin de las filas a importar.

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona pero debido a que estoy mandando como parámetro el rango de celdas a importar, recordemos que los rangos pueden variar por eso necesito que importe de una fila hacia abajo.

```vb
Public Function importarExcel(ByVal ruta As String, ByVal hoja As String, ByVal rango As String)
        Try
            'declarando las variables
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            'declarando variable de conexión
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
            ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            " Data Source='" & ruta & "'; " & _
             "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO'")
            'creando consulta para extraer contenido del archivo de excel y ejecutandola
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
                ("select * from [" & hoja & "$" & rango & "]", MyConnection)
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
            DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            'tabla.DataSet = DtSet.
            'ubicando el resultado en el datagridview
            dgvDatos.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            'cerrando conexión
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'imprimiendo mensaje de error
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: Que tal @Mario Antonio Ruiz Carrillo, me puedes aclarar si en realidad quieres hacer una búsqueda de columna por columnas y  obtener todos los registros por columna?

Comment: Hola, gracias por el apoyo, para ser más específico tengo un archivo de excel pero me gustaría importar a vb.net a partir del rango de celdas A15:I15 haci abajo hasta donde encuentre una fila vacía que indicará el fin del contenido del archivo de excel a importar

Comment: Entiendo, se me ocurre utilizar linq para  filtrar solo las filas y columnas que tengan datos. 
En un momento anexo un ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

En la función que tienes para leer el Excel puedes asignar el resultado a un DataTable por ejemplo:

```
Dim dt as DataTable = DtSet.Tables(0)
```

Después de asignar el resultado al DataTable que tienes en el DataSet, podemos utilizar una expresión linQ para extraer la información que requieres.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías recuperar los datos de las columnas que quieras:

```
 Dim query = dt .AsEnumerable() _
                .Where(Function(Columnas As DataRow) (Not IsDBNull(Columnas("NombreDeTuColumna")) AndAlso Columnas("NombreDeotraColumna") <> "") And (Not IsDBNull(Columnas("NombreDeOtraColumna")) AndAlso Columnas("NombreDeOtraColumna") <> ""))


            Dim Objs = From o In query Select New With
                   {.Columna1= o("NombreDeTuColumna"), .Columna2 = o("NombreDeotraColumna"), .Columna3 = o("NombreDeOtraColumna")}
```

De esta forma si inspeccionas los resultados tendrás un objeto EnumerableRowCollection.